# Nav Bar Menu - Covered with Contents

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm having problems with my nav bar menu when viewing in mobile. It seems that it was being covered with the contents upon scrolling. I wanted to set it to front. Please help me fix this.

My website link is [here](http://www.hotwork.ag) and please minimize it for mobile view. Refer to the image below for the problem reference.

[image: Click here to see the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a high z-index value on your nav bar.

```
#nxrmenu_bar { z-index: 9999; }
```

Comment: Thanks! This really works. What is meant for that by the way?

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.